# Printing NSManagedObject subclassed Core Data object to console returns empty line in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift, println

I am working on an Swift app with Core Data. I created my `*.xcdatamodeld` file and created a `NSManagedObject Subclass` (`Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass...`).

Everything works fine except when I try to `println` an instantiated object of that class (lets call it `Person`) the console prints blank or simply `Optional()` if not unwrapped.

I tried adding `DebugPrintable` or `Printable` via class extension without success.

Is this a known limitation of CoreData objects? What am I missing?

Adding code for clarity:

```
/// Person.swift (auto-generated by Xcode)
class Person: NSManagedObject {

   @NSManaged var firstname: String
   @NSManaged var lastname: String

}
```

My extension:

```
/// Person+Helpers.swift
extension Person : Printable, DebugPrintable {
   override var description : String {
       return "test"
   }

   override var debugDescription : String {
       return "debug test"
   }
}
```

Console prints empty line, or in the event of an array of `Person` objects, it simply prints `[ , , , , ]`

Comment: Please show the code where you instantiate the objects.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing with Xcode 6.1 (6A1052d). I created a gist to demonstrate that it doesn't matter how I get the objects: https://gist.github.com/bgrace/021f55a9f160685e2433 — I would be interested to know if Printable on an NSManagedObject is working for anybody.

Comment: I just ran into this issue as well trying to convert an array of NSManagedObject subclasses to a string to save in a bug report.

For now I'm doing this as a workaround:
var stringArray = [String]()
for subclass in arrayOfSubclass {
   stringArray.append(subclass.name)
}

Then using stringArray.description to get the joined strings.

Comment: how do you initialize Core Data? Are you using view controller containment?

Comment: I have faced same issue, though it was not blank - printed as blank..

Comment: this limitation/bug is present as of xcode 6.2 (6C131e)... have searched all over the web but didn't find any other solution different from using `NSLog`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this:

```
NSLog("My managed object: %@", managedObject)
```

For some reason, it won't output using `println` but `NSLog` works just fine.