# Core Data creates empty rows

Tags: swift, core-data

I have created a new empty project with Core Data enabled. I have added one entity and the following code in the `viewDidLoad` function of the `ViewController` class:

```
lazy var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext? =
{
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    if let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    {
        return managedObjectContext
    }
    else
    {
        return nil
    }
}()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var erreur: NSError?
    let fichier = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Bricks", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    let brick = Bricks(entity: fichier!,
        insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

    brick.levelID = 1
    brick.brickName = "test"
    brick.brickID = 1

    managedObjectContext!.save(&erreur)
    println(erreur)

    let recherche = NSFetchRequest()
    recherche.entity = fichier

    var resultat = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(recherche, error: &erreur) as [Bricks]
    println(erreur)

    println(resultat)
}
```

Everything is working fine and `erreur` returns `nil` each time, except that each row created is empty. The last `println` command return [ ] the first time, [, ] the second time, [, , ] the third time and so on

What did I miss?

Comment: I think there is a problem with the println output for NSManagedObjects in Swift - see for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526888/nsmanagedobject-description-in-swift) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599493/printing-nsmanagedobject-subclassed-core-data-object-to-console-returns-empty-li).  Try accessing the attributes for specific items in the `resultat` array - you may find everything is actually OK.

Comment: The code looks good to me. Try for example `if let result = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(recherche, error: &erreur) as? [Bricks] {
            
            for el in result {
                println("\(el.brickName)")
            }
        }`. It would just work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction : it is indeed a problem with println. All data are here.